# how to post the values dynamically from the following code

Tags: php, post

How to post the values dynamically from the following code 
I am using the following code

```
<?php
$epages_sql=mysql_query("select * from epages");
while($epapers=mysql_fetch_array($epapers_sql))
{
?>

<table>
<tr bgcolor="#FFCCFF">
    <td width="40%" height="30"><span class="style9"><?php echo $epapers['epage']; ?></span><input type="hidden" name="page_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $epapers['epage']; ?>" /></td>

    <td width="30%"><input type="file" name="file_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>" /></td>

    <td width="30%"><input type="submit" name="submit_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>"  value="Upload" class="btn_style"/></td>
</tr>

<tr  bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><td height="20"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>

<?php
 $epages_sql=mysql_query("select * from epages");
while($epapers=mysql_fetch_array($epapers_sql))
{ 
if(isset($_POST['???'])) {
 $name=$_POST['???'];
 }
}
?>
How to post this values from the above code  in ???what can i use ?
```

Please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Please explain your Question, post values you mean submit form or what??

Comment: after submit how to post these values?

Answer (score 0):

try this , Use form before start the table like in below and give action to the form

```
<?php
$epages_sql=mysql_query("select * from epages");
while($epapers=mysql_fetch_array($epapers_sql))
{
?>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="[youractionpage_name]">
<table>
<tr bgcolor="#FFCCFF">
              <td width="40%" height="30"><span class="style9"><?php echo $epapers['epage']; ?></span><input type="hidden" name="page_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $epapers['epage']; ?>" /></td>

              <td width="30%"><input type="file" name="file_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>" /></td>


    <td width="30%"><input type="submit" name="submit_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>"  value="Upload" class="btn_style"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr  bgcolor="#FFCCFF"><td height="20"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: i used form.  i am using in name="file_<?php echo $epapers['id']; ?>" how to post ?

Comment: when you click on Upload button this will submit that form, can you show your action page code here...?

Comment: <?php
$epages_sql=mysql_query("select * from epages");
while($epapers=mysql_fetch_array($epapers_sql))
{ if(isset($_POST['']))
?>

Comment: <?php
echo '<pre>';print_r($_REQUEST );echo '</pre>';


 $epages_sql=mysql_query("select * from epages");
while($epapers=mysql_fetch_array($epapers_sql))
{
if(isset($_POST['???'])) {
 $name=$_POST['???'];
 }
}
?>